# Going from uint256 to uint8, is it possible?

Tags: solidity, type-casting

I have a function that creates random numbers with a maximum value that you gives to it, the function was made to work with any uint256, and using % operator it returns a value between 0 and the maxValue that you gave to it. How could I cast from uint256 (the number that the function returns) to a uint8 for example... I now in this case the funtcion is giving a value that can be saved on a uint8, but looks like solidity doesn't.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You can just cast it:

```
uint8(number)
```

Comment: the thing is that I have a function that returns a uint256, I know it fits on a uint8, but solidity is not sure

Comment: What do you mean? Do you get some sort of error when you perform the cast? Could you share the code you're using that doesn't work?

Comment: mmm I am sorry, I tried again, and you were totally right, my mistake was not using the () properly on the cast, no in the operation...